# How to convert decimals in a matrix to integers?

Tags: matlab, matrix

If my input matrix is:

```
v =

       -0.7071    0.5774    0.4082
        0.0000   -0.5774    0.8165
        0.7071    0.5774    0.4082
```

The output should be:

```
v =
       -1         1         1
        0        -1         2
        1         1         1
```

Comment: How do you get from the input to the output??? `ceil(v*2)`???

Comment: ceil(v*2) doesn't give the desired result. I'm trying to simplify the decimals in my matrix to lowest integers.

Comment: "implify the decimals in my matrix to lowest integers" what does that mean? You have to define it.

Comment: How does `0.8` go to `2`?

Comment: Just to be "that guy", integers are also decimal values.

Comment: In other words, I want every column in my matrix to be in lowest whole numbers instead of in decimals. Taking out the common factors from every column.

Comment: In the 3rd column, dividing all elements by 0.4082 gives 1, 2, 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[A,B] = size(v)
for ii = 1:B
    v(:,ii) = v(:,ii)./abs(min(v(:,ii)));
end
```

In case this is the exact example you have.

And just in case doubles are not good enough:

```
v = int32(v); % or whichever integer you want
```

`bsxfun` way, thanks to @rayryeng:

```
v = bsxfun(@rdivide, v, abs(min(v,1)));
```

Comment: I would replace this with `v = bsxfun(@rdivide, v, abs(min(v,1)));`... it should be faster, but +1 for deciphering what the OP tried to do.

Comment: I'm rather inexperienced with functions that call anonymous functions (e.g. arrayfun, accumarray, bsxfun), so I'm always happy to learn new things, thanks!

Comment: Ah :) You're welcome. Well `bsxfun` does what is known as data broadcasting.  `rdivide` is the function that performs right array divides (i.e. `A ./ B`).  What this function call will do specifically is first find the minimum of each column of `v`, find the absolute value, then **duplicate** this vector to match the same size as `v`, then do an element-wise right divide.  This in effect performs what the loop code does.  `bsxfun` does `repmat` calls under the hood between both inputs so that they match in size, and then apply the operation on the first parameter between each of the inputs.

Comment: BTW, if you have time, come have a visit in our MATLAB chat room.  We always welcome new users to StackOverflow! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave - ... also, welcome to StackOverflow!